# Inserting value to database using Jquery and MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created a form which to insert few data into database. I am using jquery to insert the data in my mvc project but I am getting confused in how can I create insert function.

First thing, I have created a one method to Insert or Updating the record via ID. But I don't know how can I use Id as primary to check whether to Insert or Update. I know that if my ID is equal to 0 means Insert or if greater than 0 then update but how can I add that into my function. Second, I know my Insert function does not seems to be right way but what could be easier way to implement?

(View).asmx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //function will be called on button click having id btnsave
        $("#btnRoleListSubmit").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                url: '/Admin.mvc/Admin/InsertRoleList', // Controller/View   
                data: { //Passing data  
                    Name: $("#Name").val(), //Reading text box values using Jquery
                    Role: $("#Role").val(),
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="100" class="col-label">
                <span>Name</span>
            </td>
            <td class="col-label">
                <input type="text" maxlength="200" style="margin-left: 0;" name="Name" id="Name"
                    class="required" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="col-label">
                Employee Role
            </td>
            <td class="col-label">
                <textarea id="Role" name="Role" class="required" cols="15" rows="2"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
    <div style="margin: 12px;" align="center">
        <button type="submit" name="btnRoleListSubmit" class="actionButton">
            <span>Add Employee Role</span></button>
    </div>
```

(Controller).cs

```
  public ActionResult InsertRoleList(int branchId, RoleListViewModel obj)
    {
        AddDetails(branchId, obj);

        return View();
    }

     private void AddDetails(int branchId, EmailListViewModel obj)
    {

    Branch branches = this._branches.GetID(branchId);
    var GetDB = branches.GetClientDatabase();
    RoleListViewModel listData = new RoleListViewModel();
    {
        listData.Name= obj.Name;
        listData.Role= obj.Role;
    };

    List<int> lstIds = GetDB.InsertorUpadateRole(obj);
    }
```

SqlQueries.cs

```
public List<int> InsertorUpadateRole (RoleList obj)
    {
        RoleList lstData = new RoleList();
        string sqlQuery = string.Empty;
        sqlQuery = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeRoleList]
                    ([name],
                    [is_active],
                    [role],
                    [is_admin]
                    }
                    VALUES ( '{0}','1','{2}','0')
                    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id;";
        try
        {

            this.ExecuteReader((record) =>
            {
                Name = Convert.ToInt32(record["name"]);
                Role = Convert.ToInt32(record["role"]);
            },
            string.Format(sqlQuery, lstdata.Name, lstdata.Role));


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var message = e;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: _how can I use Id as primary to check whether to Insert or Update_ use an if statement in your C# code to perform either an `UPDATE` or `INSERT`

Answer (score 0):

Your url usually starts with the controller, try "/Admin/InsertRoleList".  Your ajax post parameters need to match the controller InsertRoleList(string Name, string Role) which is not very similar to your controller code...

Comment: Then what should it be solution to this?